# Is there an easy way to backup one large hard drive across several smaller hard drives?

Tags: backup

The situation: I have a 3TB hard drive which contains only my home partition. I have three 1TB hard drives that are currently empty (and an SSD which contains my root partition.)

I need to replace the 3TB drive. I want to back it up using my three smaller drives, which I guess I can do by hand but I'm wondering if there's an easy way to do it -- for example, a backup program that will automate the process and intelligently back it up across those three drives. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: How full is the 3TB drive? How big is the SSD? Would a raid array work for you?

Comment: Will you have all three 1TB drives plugged in at the same time or do you wish to shut down, swap drives and have the backup/archive program continue where it left off after reboot?

Comment: All three drives are plugged in and will stay plugged in during the whole procedure. I'll just take out the 3TB, put in another drive of the same size, and change the mount point in fstab.

Answer (score 0):

Setup the three 1TB drives as a 3TB LVM2 volume group. Using Synaptic, install lvm2 and system-config-lvm, and review the mans. Also look at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm for an overview of lvm.

Use Clonezilla (clonezilla.org or Synaptic) for backup. It supports lvm2. One flaw in Clonezilla... it will NOT backup (clone) or restore to a smaller hard disk, even if the difference is only 1 block. You'll want to investigate partition backups/restores.

You may also need CD/DVD's of 1) Ubuntu 16.04.1, 2) Clonezilla, 3)boot-repair, and 4) Windows install disk (if you have a Windows partition).

All in all, the learning curve may be a little high, but it'll do the job.

Another easy way to do this is install both old and new 3TB disks on the computer, and see if Clonezilla can do a clone copy. If it can, because the destination disk is LARGER than the source disk (even by 1 block), it would be directly bootable after removing the original 3TB hard disk.

Cheers, Al

Answer (score 0):

The "tar" command (tape archve) has always been able to handle multi-volume output (the -M switch), so try that -- with compression you might not even need all three 1T output disks.